# 2 threads one running over another

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
 private void stopThread() {
    thread1.canRun(false);
}

private void createThread() {
    thread1.stopThread();
    thread1.canRun(true);
    thread1 = new Thread(thread1);
    t.start();

}
```

Im creating a battleship game, the thread starts when the user shoots with his ship, he has n seconds to shoot and if they run out he looses the game..
when he shoots again the last thread stops and begins a new thread.
thats why i call stop thread in create thread.

```
public void canRun(boolean canrun) {
    this.canrun= canrun;
}

public thread(player player, gamej) throws RemoteException {
    this.player= player;
    this.j = j;
    tiempoTimeOut = j.getTimeout();

}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= TimeOut && canRun; i++) {

            // System.out.println(i);

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (i ==tiempoTimeOut) {
                j.notifiy();//the player lost code irrelevant
            }

            }

        }
```

the problem is, when i stopthread the for shouldnt keep running and thread finishes but i think when i start new thread canRun(true) is way ahead of "for" structure.
so it changes the variable way before the first thread finishes
so it keeps running because canRun is back to true

i think the solution is using syncrhonized somewhere
but im not sure..
help thank you

Comment: Have you declared your canrun variable as volatile?

Comment: Why is `createThread` doing `thread1.canRun(true)`? You create a new thread below that probably can run already

Comment: it cant run because to iterate over "for" one condition is canRun =true

Comment: i need the last thread running to stop..
but when i stop it and CanRun= true true for the new thread
last thread keeps continues running

Comment: Create a new instance of your Runnable (thread1) instead of rusing the same instance for your new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.currentThread.isInterruptted()` instead of the `canRun` variable.
such as

```
private void stopThread() {
    thread1.interrupt();
}

private void createThread() {
    thread1.stopThread();
    thread1 = new Thread(thread1);
    thread1.start();
}
```

and the `run` method can be like this

```
public run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= TimeOut && !Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted(); i++) {

            // System.out.println(i);

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (i ==tiempoTimeOut) {
                j.notifiy();//the player lost code irrelevant
            }

        }

    } catch ......
```